# How do you check if you are running in Medium Trust environment in .NET?

Tags: .net, medium-trust

I am running a website on shared hosting at GoDaddy (not my choice, because it is always Medium Trust), and I have some advanced features that I would like to turn on if the application is run in High Trust.

So would like to know, if there is an way to check if at runtime if the application is running in Medium Trust environment in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(new RegistryPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
{
    //do something.... not at full trust
}

if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(new DnsPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
{
    //do something.... not at full trust
}
```

I got this from the following link:
http://www.netomatix.com/development/webcaspermissions.aspx

here's links for the Security Manager and Registry Permission classes in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitymanager.isgranted.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermission.aspx

You will need to add a reference to System.Security and add a couple of using statements for System.Security and System.Security.Permissions.

EDIT:

Added after Nick's Comment:

You could test directly for the asp.net security level:

```
if (SecurityManager.IsGranted( new AspNetHostingPermission(AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium)))
{Response.Write("Medium Trust level");}
```

Comment: I think for ASP.NET, the AspNetHostingPermission, is a better fit.

Comment: Good Catch Nick.  I added it as an example.

Comment: .net 4.0 has made setting permissions in this way depricated.