# The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAcces.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception

Tags: c#, oracle

When I try to connect to an Oracle database in my C# application and I try to click a button I get this error:

> The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAcces.Client.OracleConnection'
>   threw an exception

My code for accessing the database:

```
        static string column;
        static string OracleServer = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=something)(HOST=something)(PORT=something)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=name)));User Id=something;Password=something;";

        public void read()
        {
            try
            {
                var conn = new OracleConnection(OracleServer);
                conn.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from t1", conn);
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var column1 = reader["vermogen"];
                    column = (column1.ToString());
                    listBox1.Items.Add(column);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Now I am using the reference `Oracle.DataAccess` and as code: `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;`

The application is an arcgis add in application, and I converted it to a form application and it does connect to the database. But I have to have it work in the add in application.

I have never experienced this error and I am not experienced at Oracle databases and I was wondering what is causing this error? When I run the application, I dont get any errors. But when I click the buttons of the User Interface of the application, I get this error.

What should I do to lose the error and what is causing it?

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen if your Oracle client DLL version number is **mildly** different from the reference you have in Visual Studio and even if you set that reference's "Specific Version" property to false.

Answer (score 6):

This is an error inside the Oracle dll. My guess is that you installed the .NET dlls but did not install the Oracle client on your system. Can you connect to Oracle through the SQLPlus client software? If it's not installed, you need to install the Oracle client software.

Comment: I can connect through sql developer. But when I try to click on connect identifier I get: Status : Failure -Test failed: Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:112020, Jdbc-OCI:112030

Comment: So you can *not* connect through sql developer? You need the Oracle client software installed! Do you have SQLPlus on your PC? If not, it's a good indicator that you do not have the Oracle client installed.

Comment: well I can connect with network aliases but not through connect identifier. I'll try sqlplus.

Comment: ok, great. Then it's probably not a .NET problem, find the problem with your Oracle connection and fix it.

Comment: The application is an arcgis add in application, and I converted it to a form application and it does connect to the database. But I have to have it work in the add in application.

Comment: You cannot connect to the database. Not with your application and not without. Fix your computer setup or database setup so you can connect to the database (ask your DBA or on dba.stackexchange.com). If you don't do this, nothing you do with your application will help.

Comment: But how is it possible to connect with the database with a form application?

Comment: Your code looks good. If your database connection were running, it would probably work. Again: *this is a problem with your computer connecting to this database* **in general**. Fix it.

Comment: I know the code is good, since I use the same code for the form application. Anyway I'll look into it...

Comment: This error can occur if there is any problem with the connection.  This drove me nuts for hours, since I had the Oracle bin in my path and everything. It turned out my system administrator did not install the networking/TNS part of the installation (just the "thin client"). Once I upgraded the Oracle installation to an Administrative installation, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Change your project properties.
Build section, Palatform : x86

Comment: A small explanation of why this fixes the OP's problem could be helpful.

Comment: I had similar issue, but changing to Platform: Any CPU was the solution for me.

Comment: The dll for oracle access are available for 32 or 64 platforms. This could be the source of confusion.

Comment: What if someone is building the x64 version?  I wouldn't suggest x86 without knowing what was installed.

Use gacutil utility from Microsoft to analyze the GAC with:
gacutil /l Oracle.DataAccess

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have administrator permission for `Oracle Client`. Add this in `App.config` file :

```
<IPermission class="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OraclePermission,
 Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" version= "1" Unrestricted="true"/>
```

Comment: Add this where in the .config file, under <configuration>?

Comment: `IPermission` section is a part of CAS policy files that are located at `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\CONFIG`

Comment: Note that as of .NET 4.0 runtime doesn't use CAS policy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229231/how-can-i-run-an-exe-or-windows-service-in-medium-trust/8243099#8243099) for more details.