# Windows Service written in C# has issues with log4net when run as a Service

Tags: c#, .net, service, log4net

I have a C# service that works fine in my development environment but crashes without any error logged to my log file or database when we try building it in our testing environment. The only clue I get from the Windows Services manager is:

> "The [My Service] service on Local Computer started and then stopped.
>   Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other
>   services or programs".

When we tried running the service from command prompt to debug it, it worked just fine. Although my log file didn't have any error messages, there were several status messages to let me know when each section of code was executing. Fortunately, the code seemed to fail between two status messages with only three lines of code between them:

```
//line 1
AssemblyName myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();

//line 2
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["applicationName"] = string.Format("{0}, {1}",myAssembly.Name, myAssembly.Version);

//line 3
RequestWorkerThreadControlExtender.SetStarting();
```

I'm beginning to think that it has something to do with whatever permissions log4net uses to get the executing assembly in line 1. The Windows Service ran as a custom service account, but our successful attempt to run the code through the command prompt ran as administrator. Are there any special permissions my service account needs to run this code?

Under normal circumstances, I would try debugging this in the testing server since I can't reproduce the error in my development environment. However, my workplace is very strict about building in the test environment. I have to get several people to signoff on my code before building in that server, so I'd prefer to debug outside the server, if at all possible. (In hindsight, I should have tried running the command prompt as a service user instead of admin, but I didn't think of that, at the time).

For reference,  the function referenced by line 3 is:

```
 public void SetStarting()
        {
            ControlSignal = ServiceControlSignal.STARTING;
        }
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas about the permissions required for  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();` or how I could debug this given my current limitations. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the Event Log for any clues?

Comment: Did you check if any of the objects you use are null ?

Comment: The only clue I found in the event log was a generic message saying that my service didn't start.

Comment: I've not checked for nulls in the testing environment, but I know that none of those lines of code that I shared above are null in the dev environment. My guess is that some error in `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()` is causing AssemblyName myAssembly to equal null, but I can't figure out what that would be. In both testing and dev, this variable is supposed to pull data from my AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: Are you allowed to install the remote debugging tools on the test machine? If so create a debug build with Debugger.Break() the first line of code in the service, e.g. in Program.Main. When you start the service you'll get a popup - attach your debugger remotely and then close the popup and see what the problem is.

If you can't do that, install an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException then do detailed tracing to a plain text file in their, including unrolling any inner exceptions.

Comment: Getting the assembly from a known type in it - i.e. `typeof(TypeInAssembly).Assembly` - is cleaner. However unless the service [is explicitly using permission limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8243099/43846) then there is no reason it would fail due to permissions. Redeploying with some more logging code and an unhandled exception handler as suggested by @donovan is probably the best next step.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add in the logging code and unhandled exception handler to my build and see if I can at least get a clearer diagnosis of the problem.